# conversion of array values except first element

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array as following :

```
var myArray = [['aaa','33','34.5','23'],['bbb','35','34.5','63'],['ccc','53','34.5','25'],['ddd','33','34.5','3']]
```

I want to convert all values into float except first element in each array.
So result will be like this :

`var myArray = [['aaa',33,34.5,23],['bbb',35,34.5,63],['ccc',53,34.5,25],['ddd',33,34.5,3]]`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any attempts ?? We are not here to do your job.

Answer (score 1):

simply Try with [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilwN3fgsfTAhXKLo8KHQqnACMQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=dNdf2e3UBx_PXWwLdHHz9Q) and [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjZudXwgsfTAhVGMI8KHVc_DRIQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_parsefloat.asp&usg=AFQjCNHnX2N78WPvEGHs8qefO1xV4Wm98A&sig2=6d1HBgztK0nwmbPnlMnKgw) `b != 0` it will prevent the first argument of the array

***without Arrow function(for safari)***

```js
var myArray = [
  ['aaa', '33', '34.5', '23'],
  ['bbb', '35', '34.5', '63'],
  ['ccc', '53', '34.5', '25'],
  ['ddd', '33', '34.5', '3']
];

console.log(myArray.map(function(a) {
  return a.map(function(a, b) {
    return b != 0 ? parseFloat(a) : a;
  })
}))
```

***With arrow function***

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','33','34.5','23'],['bbb','35','34.5','63'],['ccc','53','34.5','25'],['ddd','33','34.5','3']];

console.log(myArray.map(a => a.map((a,b) => b != 0 ? parseFloat(a): a)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But shows a syntax error in in Safari like _SyntaxError : Unexpected Token : '>'_.

Comment: @Vahid see my updated answer. i was added without arrow function.try this out

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and the inner array and assign only converted values, if the index is greater than zero.

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','33','34.5','23'],['bbb','35','34.5','63'],['ccc','53','34.5','25'],['ddd','33','34.5','3']]

myArray.forEach(a => a.forEach((b, i, bb) => i && (bb[i] = +b)));

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','33','34.5','23'],['bbb','35','34.5','63'],['ccc','53','34.5','25'],['ddd','33','34.5','3']]

myArray.forEach(function (a) { a.forEach(function (b, i, bb) { i && (bb[i] = +b); }); });

console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But shows a syntax error in in Safari like _SyntaxError : Unexpected Token : '>'_.

Comment: @Vahid, please try option 2 with classic javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and then `slice()` from each array sub-array from first element transform it to numbers and concat to new array.

```js
var myArray = [['aaa','33','34.5','23'],['bbb','35','34.5','63'],['ccc','53','34.5','25'],['ddd','33','34.5','3']]

var result = myArray.map(e => [e[0]].concat(...e.slice(1).map(parseFloat)));
console.log(result)
```